# why __getitem__ cannot be classmethod?

Tags: python, class-method

Suppose following class:

```
class Class(object):
    @classmethod
    def getitem(*args):
        print 'getitem %s' % (args,)
    @classmethod
    def __getitem__(*args):
        print '__getitem__ %s' % (args,)
```

The getitem method behaves as expected: it receives `Class` as first arg, but `__getitem__` receives `type` as first arg:

```
calling Class.getitem(test)
getitem (<class '__main__.Class'>, 'test')

calling obj.getitem(test)
getitem (<class '__main__.Class'>, 'test')

calling Class[test]
'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

calling obj[test]
__getitem__ (<class '__main__.Class'>, 'test')
```

What is the magic there behind `__getitem__` ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Special methods are looked up on the class, and not on the instance - unlike regular methods that are looked up on the instance first. See [Special method lookup](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes) in the Python data model docs.

Thinking about `Class` as an instance of `type`, this means when you do

```
Class.getitem(test)
```

It looks first for exactly what you tell it: a method in `Class`'s own attributes called `getitem`. But, when you use

```
Class[test]
```

it skips this, and goes straight to `type` (being the class of `Class`, or its metaclass), and so calls `type.__getitem__(Class, test)`. So, what's happening isn't that `__getitem__` gets `type` as its first argument (it would still get `Class`, as it does if you explicitly `Class.__getitem__(test)`), its that the `__getitem__` that Python looks for in this case doesn't exist. To make it exist, you need to define your own metaclass for `Class` that defines it as an instance method, rather than defining it on `Class` as a classmethod.

Comment: `Thinking about Class as an instance of type`. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

When you call `x[test]`, the interpreter inspects `type(x)` for the `__getitem__` attribute. In case of `Class[test]` it's the `Class`'s metaclass, i.e. `type`. If you want to have a class-wide `__getitem__`, define it inside a new metaclass. (Needless to say, that's a sort of magic, as anything you do with metaclasses)

```
class Meta(type):
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        print "__getitem__:", arg


class X(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

X['hello'] # output: __getitem__ hello
```

Comment: Thats's the solution for the question stated, but it's too much coding for such syntactic sugar.
And in actual code i'm trying to __getitem__ on metaclass itself :)