# Issue extending Enum and redefining __getitem__

Tags: python-3.x, enums

I am having some trouble redefining `__getitem__` on a custom subclass of `Enum`. My `__getitem__` is not being called. I guess it has something to do with `Enum`'s metaclass, but I am not sure what and why.

Minimal working example (Python 3.4):

```
from enum import Enum, unique

@unique
class Test(Enum):
    a = "a"
    b = "b"

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(name)
        except (TypeError, KeyError) as error:
            print("TEST")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test["a"]
    Test["c"]
```

Result:

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    Test["c"]
  File "C:\Development\Python\Python34\lib\enum.py", line 258, in __getitem__
    return cls._member_map_[name]
KeyError: 'c'
```

Comment: Potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12447036/3001761

Comment: why are you redefining `__getitem__`, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your overriding of `__getitem__` would be invoked if you use square-brackets on an *instance* of an `Enum`.

Accessing it like `Test["A"]` would invoke the `__getitem__` method of the meta-class. So in your case, you'd need to subclass the `EnumMeta` meta-class, overriding its `__getitem__`, then create your own enum class with that meta class.

You can take a look at the source code [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/enum.py).

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to get around it with @classmethod?

Comment: no. It should be clear after you read the answers in the link posted by @jonrsharpe

Comment: I actually asked before seeing there was a comment. It does make some sense now.

Answer (score 13):

As @shx2 pointed out, you're not invoking the `__getitem__()` of your`Enum` subclass. Here's how to fix that by also subclassing `Enum`'s metaclass:

```
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta, unique

class TestEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(name)
        except (TypeError, KeyError) as error:
            print("TEST")

@unique
class Test(Enum, metaclass=TestEnumMeta):
    a = "a"
    b = "b"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test["a"]
    Test["c"]  # -> TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Enum similar to typescript Enum this is your best call:

```py
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta, unique
class TestEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __getitem__(self, indexOrName):
        if isinstance(indexOrName, str):
            return super().__getitem__(indexOrName).value
        elif isinstance(indexOrName, int) and indexOrName < super().__len__():
            return list(self)[indexOrName].name


@unique
class CustomEnum(Enum, metaclass=TestEnumMeta):
    pass
```

Example:

- few example lines and prints:

```py
ExamEnum(CustomEnum):
   Zero=0
   One=1
   Two=2

>>> ExamEnum['Zero']
0
>>> ExamEnum[0]
Zero
>>> ExamEnum.One
1
```

- when you access the `ExamEnum` you will get all the properties autocomplete